# How to make Shoe move w/ Human Model?

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, parent

I have two separate models, one of a person and the other of a pair of shoes. The human model is fully rigged but I don't know how to make the shoe move with the model's foot. Anyone know how to fix this? Or should I make the shoe on the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both solutions are ok: you can either separate the shoe or join it to the rest of the body.

If you choose to separate, first delete the *Armature* modifier if it ever exists, then keep the shoe selected in *Object* mode, shift select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, select the foot bone and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *(Set Parent to) > Bone*.

If you choose to join the shoe to the rest of the body <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, once joined, select the shoe mesh (<kbd>L</kbd>), go into the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups*, on the right of the list click on the down arrow and click on *Remove from All Groups*, then in the list select the shoe vertex group (that has the name of the foot bone) and click on the *Assign* button that is under the list.